# Need to achieve a specific CSS Layout

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment, styling

and first of all sorry for that bad caption.

Alright.. i need to achieve this layout :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWLRY.png

So far i got this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie5Lj.png

my Problem is, that i can align the leftBar, Content, rightBar next to each other.. But i want the Bars to go straight to the Bottom and in between them ( below Content ) my 3 Boxes next to each other.

How could i get this done ? Thanks for every reply!

Here is the first try :

```
/* Contains everything below */
.webContainer { 
    width: 100%;
}

/* Side Bars */
.leftBar, .rightBar{
    width: 15%;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
}

/* Slider between 2 Bars */
.slider {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

/* Boxes below Slider */
.firstBox, .secondBox, .thirdBox {
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;

}
```

The HTML looks something like this :

```
<div class="webContainer">

   <div class="leftBar">
     //leftBar Content
   </div>

   <div class="slider">
      //Slider code
   </div>

   <div class="rightBar">
     //rightBar Content
   </div>

   <div class="fistBox">
     //Content
   </div>
   <div class="secondBox">
     //Content
   </div>
   <div class="thirdBox">
     //Content
   </div>

</div>
```

Thanks for any Help!

EDIT : Thanks for the answers, i already marked the best one in my opinion. Also the HTML i posted is only a piece of code for you guys to have an idea what im building..  I am using PHP and each part is in an different PHP file.. so the actual code is way more "compicated" - this should just give an idea.

Comment: What browser support do you need? If you don't require lower IE support, you can use flexbox to do this pretty easily.

Comment: You could also wrap '.slider' and the 3 boxes with a div to make it more simple and logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtx2sn15/)

Float your .rightBar to the right

```
.rightBar {
    float: right;
}
```

And delete your typo in your html. **.firstBox** instead of **.fistBox**. (Notice the R).

Answer (score 0):

view it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oussamaelgoumri/a74xovj7/)

another solution using position, to make the layout fluid.

its not the perfect one, because am not a designer, but it should give you an idea on how to solve this probleme

```
body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightgreen;
}

.left-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
}

.right-bar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 100px;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container .slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: red;
}

.container .box-1 {
    width: 33.3%;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container .box-2 {
    width: 33.3%;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 33.3%;
}

.container .box-3 {
    width: 33.4%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 66.6%;
}
```

the html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<header></header>
<div class="left-bar"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="right-bar"></div>
```

Comment: I prefer using "dynamic" positions like float: left.. No absolutes. Also fixed widths are not "dynamic" also. Thanks for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find code at http://jsfiddle.net/zxxpuzct/

Below is the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
div{
border:1px solid red;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.webContainer
{
width:600px;
    height:600px;
}
.leftBar, .rightBar{
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
}
 .rightBar{
 float:right;
}
.leftBar{
float:left;    
}
.slider{
    width:70%;
    height:25%;
    float:left;
 }
.firstBox, .secondBox, .thirdBox {
    width: 23.333%;
    height: 75%;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="webContainer">

   <div class="leftBar">
     //leftBar Content
   </div>

   <div class="slider">
      //Slider code
   </div>

   <div class="rightBar">
     //rightBar Content
   </div>

   <div class="firstBox">
     //Content
   </div>
   <div class="secondBox">
     //Content
   </div>
   <div class="thirdBox">
     //Content
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used inner border for better visibility of div. Set your required width and height for webContainer.  You have spelling mistake in your question at   :)